# A message to clients in the dashboard widget received from another site

Tags: widgets, dashboard, iframe

I would like to display various notifications on the dashboard of client sites. This is not a list of posts, just a message. The message itself is located on my main site. That is, I change the messages on my site and it is displayed accordingly in the dashboard widget on client sites.

Now I do this by adding a widget with an iframe. But this seems to me a bad decision. In addition, the fixed height in the iframe is a big hindrance.

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/dash_widget/" width="100%" height="250px"></iframe>
```

Tell me, please, is there any more reliable design for the implementation of this task? Maybe someone has already done this.

Answer (score 0):

No, iframe is not a good desicion. The best option is creating a custom api. Wordpress has a REST API with the ability to add custom endpoints:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

If you're familiar enoigh with coding, you can create a custom api that shows the message that you want and in the client site, write a code for the dashboard widget to get the code.